# How to hide tabs from My Account portlet in Liferay's Control Panel

Tags: menu, navigation, liferay, customization, control-panel

Folks,

I need to get rid of all the unnecessary stuff in the left navigation of My Account portlet. I tried to remove the items from /html/portlet/enterprise_admin/categories_navigation.jspf but couldn't find a way to do so. Any hints are very appreciated.

Greetz,
Erik

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to configure which tabs are displayed in My Account portlet and doesn't even require modifications of any jsps. You just need to override some properties from portal.properties. I have described this detailed in my [blog post](http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/clean-up-control-panel-from-unnecessary.html).

http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/clean-up-control-panel-from-unnecessary.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override portal.properties (which requires restart), all you need to do is remove permissions from the appropriate role. All doable in Control Panel on the fly.

As described here [How to disable Control-panel's "My Account" Portlet for only Power-user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261469/how-to-disable-control-panels-my-account-portlet-for-only-power-user-role)