# How to disable Control-panel's "My Account" Portlet for only Power-user role

Tags: liferay, role

I want to disable (remove access) for `Control Panel > My Account` portlet for `Power-user` role or for my custom user.

It should display for `Administrator` role. Is there any portal properties or some other configuration?

Or do we need to achieve something through coding?

Comment: It would help if you could paste a screen-shot of the things you don't want Power Users to access. Or else the answer by @Jonny is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would suggest you do the following:

1) Go into the Control Panel
2) Go to "Roles" under the "Portal" section
3) Go to "Actions" -> "Define Permissions" for the Power User role (or any other role you want to change)
4) Click "Delete" next to all permissions you want to remove from that role.

Changing them in portal-ext.properties will change them for all users, so this is your best approach.

Comment: Power Users do have permission/access to go to Control Panel and view the `My Account` portlet.

Comment: Thanks Prakash, must just be something we've done to our Power User role then as it didn't have it. I've edited my answer accordingly to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the procedure in the other answer works. I doubt it for the version 6.0.6.

Another approach is to remove the My Accounts portlet from Liferay. To do so, open the file `liferay-portlet.xml` in `<Liferay>/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/` and remove the portlet entry with the portlet-name 2.

Note: If you do so: no user will be able to view this portlet. But administrators are able to view the Users portlet and they can change their account at that location.